# JQM + Knockout and group of checkboxes

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox, knockout.js

I am trying to bind to a list in JQM from knockout. The data is coming across just fine and I am able to view the group of checkboxes the issue is that the checkboxes are being styled as JQM checkboxes, they are being left as regular checkboxes. Here is what I have:
HTML

```
        <div data-role="content">       
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend></legend>
                <!-- ko foreach: orders -->
                    <li class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-b" data-role="list-divider" data-bind="text: CustomerName"></li>
                    <!-- ko foreach: Orders -->
                        <input type="checkbox" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="attr: { name: 'chk-' + OrderNum + '_' + CustNum, id: 'chk-' + OrderNum + '_' + CustNum }" />
                        <label data-bind="text: 'Order: ' + OrderNum, attr: { for: 'chk-' + OrderNum + '_' + CustNum }"></label>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </fieldset>         

        </div>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$("#orders").on("pageinit", function () {
            console.log("orders.pageinit");
            ko.applyBindings(new OrderVM());

                         console.log("before create");
            $("#orders").trigger("create");
            console.log("after create");
        });
```

Comment: `.controlgroup().trigger('create')`.

Comment: That does work to convert it over (tried it through google dev) but when I replace $("#orders").trigger("create") with $("#orders").controlgroup().trigger("create") it does not show anything. The only way that I have got it to show was adding it to the $(window).load I am populating the checkboxes with an AJAX call to a web service, so i think that that i need to wait until the AJAX call has completed here is my code for that:

Comment: function OrderVM() {
    console.log("ordervm");

    var self = this;
    self.orders = ko.observableArray();

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8003/Api/Orders/GetOpenOrderNumbersGroupByCustName", self.orders);

}